# How do you get the url of wordpress plugin from template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working for a client right now that is wanting me to author a wordpress plugin for them, and on top of that they want me to integrate it into their template as a feature. However since the url of the location of the plugin could change I want to be able to call the loaded plugin from the template, however I am not finding any good way to do so. I have read over [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) and not found a function that suits what I need, or I simply don't understand what they are doing. I am not familiar with how WordPress loads and uses plugins. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wordpress has a built in function to find the path to your plugin, similar to this:

```
$pluginpath =  plugin_dir_url(your_plugin.php);
```

I believe that is what you are asking, no? Or are you referring to sending a function from the plugin to the template? In that case, you have to use an action hook. Here is the reference: [Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

Comment: I wanted to call the plugin from the template.

Comment: As in activate it, initialize it, and everything through your template files? Not possible as far as I know. You have to set it up in the plugin's folder and use the admin panel.

Comment: I figured out how to do it, I ended up using that plus some other features with AJAX etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [WP overview on plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

In short, plugins are managed by the WP install and once activated automatically load when the pages are called. Plugin files are stored in: wp-content/plugins/ and are stored within each individual WP installation. As long as your client doesn't mess with the wp-content directory structure, your plugin should load if activated in the WP admin console (and it's functional/doesn't break). This is the only way to run plugins through WP as of now (though I don't see this changing).